# Interpreting summary of mixed-effects model R (metafor)

Tags: r, meta-analysis, coefficient-of-variation

I am a complete novice and was hoping for some clarity around interpretation of my results. Note the response ratio I am interested in is the log coefficient of variation ratio (lnCVR). Please see a small sample of data - though it is unlikely to help provide meaningful results:

```
organism_detail veg_community   measure t_mean  t_sd    t_se    t_cv    t_quad_n    t_qsize_linearm2/time   t_qsize_m2  t_ssize_ha  r_mean  r_sd    r_se    r_cv    r_quad_n    r_qsize_linear  r_qsize_m2  r_ssize_ha  c_mean  c_sd    c_se    c_cv    c_quad_n    c_qsize_linear  c_qsize_m2  c_ssize_ha  age(rest)   site_size
Lepidoptera forest  Shan_div    21.4    14.9    2.483333333 0.696261682 32      NA  500 23.7    15.5    4.474464586 0.654008439 32      NA  500 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA      NA  NA  4   500
Lepidoptera forest  sp_rich 47.4    26  4.333333333 0.548523207 32      NA  500 62.8    38.2    11.02739014 0.608280255 32      NA  500 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA      NA  NA  4   500
grassland   grassland   even    0.777122531 0.071366376 0.02256803  0.091834136 10      1   1   0.8200173   0.045861093 0.014502551 0.055926982 10      1   1   0.782245149 0.051514245 0.016290235 0.065854349 10      1   1   3   1
grassland   grassland   even    0.761176052 0.040258669 0.012730909 0.052890089 10      1   1   0.8200173   0.045861093 0.014502551 0.055926982 10      1   1   0.782245149 0.051514245 0.016290235 0.065854349 10      1   1   3   1
grassland   grassland   even    0.727425674 0.047416787 0.014994505 0.065184374 10      1   1   0.8200173   0.045861093 0.014502551 0.055926982 10      1   1   0.782245149 0.051514245 0.016290235 0.065854349 10      1   1   3   1
grassland   grassland   even    0.848294027 0.080334923 0.025404133 0.094701743 10      1   1   0.8200173   0.045861093 0.014502551 0.055926982 10      1   1   0.782245149 0.051514245 0.016290235 0.065854349 10      1   1   3   1
grassland   grassland   Shan_div    4.190501692 0.396927242 0.125519415 0.094720697 10      1   1   4.722399781 0.312866417 0.098937048 0.066251574 10      1   1   3.438504231 0.304240111 0.096209171 0.088480365 10      1   1   3   1
grassland   grassland   Shan_div    4.079693163 0.30924688  0.09779245  0.075801505 10      1   1   4.722399781 0.312866417 0.098937048 0.066251574 10      1   1   3.438504231 0.304240111 0.096209171 0.088480365 10      1   1   3   1
grassland   grassland   Shan_div    4.004381201 0.37002005  0.117010614 0.092403803 10      1   1   4.722399781 0.312866417 0.098937048 0.066251574 10      1   1   3.438504231 0.304240111 0.096209171 0.088480365 10      1   1   3   1
grassland   grassland   Shan_div    4.519671132 0.592600506 0.187396734 0.131115846 10      1   1   4.722399781 0.312866417 0.098937048 0.066251574 10      1   1   3.438504231 0.304240111 0.096209171 0.088480365 10      1   1   3   1
grassland   grassland   sp_rich 36.5    4.352521619 1.376388188 0.119247168 10      1   1   42.8    3.938414797 1.245436113 0.092019037 10      1   1   34.49141414 6.397800753 2.02316224  0.185489662 10      1   1   1   1
grassland   grassland   sp_rich 37.6    5.796550698 1.833030278 0.154163582 10      1   1   42.8    3.938414797 1.245436113 0.092019037 10      1   1   34.49141414 6.397800753 2.02316224  0.185489662 10      1   1   1   1
grassland   grassland   sp_rich 39.6    6.801960502 2.150968774 0.171766679 10      1   1   42.8    3.938414797 1.245436113 0.092019037 10      1   1   34.49141414 6.397800753 2.02316224  0.185489662 10      1   1   1   1
grassland   grassland   sp_rich 32.33333333 4.415880433 1.396424004 0.136573622 10      1   1   42.8    3.938414797 1.245436113 0.092019037 10      1   1   34.49141414 6.397800753 2.02316224  0.185489662 10      1   1   1   1
grassland   grassland   sp_rich 39.5    4.600724581 1.454876856 0.11647404  10      1   1   50.22222222 4.381146476 1.385440163 0.087235217 10      1   1   34.49141414 6.397800753 2.02316224  0.185489662 10      1   1   2   1
grassland   grassland   sp_rich 39.9    6.172519745 1.95192213  0.154699743 10      1   1   50.22222222 4.381146476 1.385440163 0.087235217 10      1   1   34.49141414 6.397800753 2.02316224  0.185489662 10      1   1   2   1
```

I am trying to understand the cause of a change in the variance of the treatment group (t_mean, t_sd, etc.). There are two control groups, but for simplicities sake I am currently only interested in the "c" group (c_mean, etc.). Now, using the code I have pasted at the bottom of this question, I get the following output. I was after some advice on this.

```
Mixed-Effects Model (k = 344; tau^2 estimator: REML)

   logLik   deviance        AIC        BIC       AICc 
-359.4915   718.9830   728.9830   748.1277   729.1626   

tau^2 (estimated amount of residual heterogeneity):     0.1577 (SE = 0.0278)
tau (square root of estimated tau^2 value):             0.3971
I^2 (residual heterogeneity / unaccounted variability): 52.16%
H^2 (unaccounted variability / sampling variability):   2.09
R^2 (amount of heterogeneity accounted for):            38.54%

Test for Residual Heterogeneity:
QE(df = 340) = 857.1654, p-val < .0001

Test of Moderators (coefficients 2:4):
QM(df = 3) = 113.7937, p-val < .0001

Model Results:

            estimate      se     zval    pval    ci.lb    ci.ub 
intrcpt      -0.1758  0.0619  -2.8393  0.0045  -0.2972  -0.0545   ** 
r_cv          1.7251  0.2301   7.4979  <.0001   1.2742   2.1761  *** 
c_cv         -1.6457  0.1812  -9.0820  <.0001  -2.0009  -1.2906  *** 
t_qsize_m2   -0.0001  0.0000  -1.9625  0.0497  -0.0001  -0.0000    * 

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

My main questions are:

1. Is it completely asinine to use the coefficient of variation (CV) of one of the groups as a moderator to understand the lnCVR? To elaborate, the question I am *trying* to ask by doing so is whether a high or low variance in the control group explains future high or low variance in the treatment group. Further to this, how do I understand the positive and negative intercepts (r_cv, and c_cv in the model)?
2. Does the R^2 subtract this variance from the I^2? I.e. is the unnaccounted variability calculated taking into account the R^2? If so, why when I run without moderators is the I^2 not equal to the I^2+R^2 from the moderator model?
3. The last thing I am confused about two aspects of the intercept. To understand the effect of **t** on **c** should I use the intercept from a random model without moderators, yes? I can't fully comprehend why this changes but I assume this is the intercept on data with moderators incorporated. I.e. the significant p-value indicates there is another variable moderating the variance to a significant degree that I am not accounting for?
4. How do I interpret this figure? If I use exp(-0.2687) (this is the intercept when I run a random-effects model without moderators), I get 0.7643. Can I interpret this as the variance in the treatment group being 76.43% of the variance in the control group?

---

```
CVR<-escalc(measure = "CVR", n1i = dat$t_quad_n, n2i = dat$c_quad_n, 
           m1i = dat$t_mean, m2i = dat$c_mean, sd1i = dat$t_sd, sd2i = dat$c_sd)

dat <-bind_cols(dat, CVR)

dat[, "wi"] <- 1/dat$vi

v_rma <- rma(yi = yi, vi = vi, weights = wi,mods = ~r_cv+c_cv+t_qsize_m2, method = "REML", 
               data = dat)
summary(v_rma)
```

Comment: For anyone else playing at home, I found a comment from Wolfgang linking to an explanation on these things in the metafor package documention [here](http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:multiple_factors_interactions)

Comment: Glad to hear you found this useful. This aside, unless you have good reasons to do so, don't use custom weights (using the `weights` argument). The default behavior is to use inverse variance weights, but in a RE model, the weights are $w_i = 1 / (v_i + \hat{\tau}^2)$.

Comment: Oh, thanks for that. Noted. Did you have any comment on Q1? In the documentation I linked above, explain the moderators as effects of levels of factors on the intercept. I find this easier to conceptualize. How do you interpret a coefficient like above when it is numeric. Does c_cv in the model above say the average effect (lnCVR) is lower as c_cv increases? i.e. higher variance in control results in greater reduction of variation in treatment? Many thanks.

Comment: Can't seem to edit my previous comment, so sorry for the spam. When I plot c_cv against yi, this seems to illustrate what I was assuming above. Greater reduction in variance (lnCVR) when initial (control) cv is higher. Pretty axiomatic but interesting to know that it explains a lot in the model.

Comment: To examine 1. you should look into using a bivariate model. See: http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/analyses:vanhouwelingen2002 (different effect size / outcome measure, but the idea is the same).